# Angular Can't bind to 'ngModel' With FormsModule already imported

Tags: angular, typescript

Note : I'm not a front end dev, even if I do a bit of it. If anything you see can be improved, do not hesitate to share ;)

Strange behavior here, I can't find out why.
I have the famous "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." in the console. But  "FormsModule" is imported in the corresponding @Module, which contains the component on the declarations array. So I can't find a solutions on the already answered questions (or if you find, tell me how ;) ).
The module :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';


import { UserPreferencesComponent } from './user-preferences/user-preferences.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserPreferencesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class UserPreferencesModule { }
```

The component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { UserPreferences } from '../../entities/UserPreferences';
import { UserPreferencesService } from '../../services/user-preferences.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'acm-user-preferences',
  templateUrl: './user-preferences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-preferences.component.scss']
})
export class UserPreferencesComponent implements OnInit {
  public userPrefs: UserPreferences;
  public foo: number;

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService, private userPreferencesService: UserPreferencesService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userPreferencesService.getUserPreferences('default').subscribe(userPref => {
      this.userPrefs = userPref;
    });
  }
}
```

The html template

```
<h1>Preferences</h1>>
<input [(ngModel)]="foo">
```

The error in the console

```
Error: src/app/user-preferences/user-preferences/user-preferences.component.html:13:8 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

13 <input [(ngModel)]="foo">
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/user-preferences/user-preferences/user-preferences.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './user-preferences.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UserPreferencesComponent.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "X",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint && npx htmlhint \"**/*.html\" && npx stylelint \"**/*.css\" \"**/*.scss\"",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.3",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-mydatepicker": "^0.11.5",
    "angular-spinner": "^1.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.20.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^3.0.8",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^13.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^13.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^37.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "htmlhint": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^13.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "postcss-scss": "^4.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "set-value": "^4.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^14.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "set-value": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

At this point I'm lost, I don't know where I have done something wrong....

Comment: Did you also import `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts` as well ?

Comment: Yes, juste in case, but doesn't change a bit.
It does work in another module, and I can't find the difference --'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some times, I finally found it : I did not imported the UserPreferencesModule in the AppModule... So simple, yet so many times...
Have a nice day every one !

Answer (score 1):

Please import the below code in your "UserPreferencesModule" module file

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and below code add in imports array

```
imports : [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ]
```

if you don't want to create a `<form>` then add this code in your input

```
[(ngModel)]="foo" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Hope, it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, worth the try, even if no luck :
```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```
Seems like the compiler does not see the FormsModule import, but the UserPreferencesComponent is in the declarations array of the module, so I'm really lost...

Comment: Please visit this link 
[Click..](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/cant-bind-to-ngmodel-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input/#:~:text=In%20Angular%20applications%2C%20If%20you,ts%20file.)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't add anything. FormsModule is already imported in what I think is the corresponding module.